# Detect android webview resource load failure

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there any way to detect resource load error events? (e.g. images) 
Currently there is the `onReceivedError` event in the `WebViewClient` which handles unrecoverable errors. I'm interested mainly in listening to image load error events.

Comment: did you find any solution for it?